Problemas con permisos para ejaular usuarios en /var/www/sitiouno sobre debian
Amigos, tengo un problema de permisos, para ejaular un usuario en la ruta /var/www/sitiouno, ya que no consigo que conecte por el cliente ftp.

Esta es la configuración que tengo en sftp y la siguiente en la estructura de directorios.

Ya tengo el usuario web uno agregado al grupo www-data.
root@httpds:/var/www/sitiouno# id -Gn webuno
webuno www-data
tambien tengo el usuario apuntando a esta estructura de carpetas sin posibilidad de no loguearse por shell.
webuno:x:1006:1007::/var/www/sitiouno:/bin/false
aun asi desde filezilla no consigo conectar, como si tuviera un problema de permisos en la carpeta.
Que podrá estar mal?
Cordial saludo.

que significa ejaular?

Que no se salgan de sus propios directorios, solo podrían ver el suyo no de nadie mas.

ya veo, y para eso cada uno debería de tener un rol de usuario diferente y acceder con el rol distinto. ¿O entiendo mal?

El problema parece ser que la carpeta /var/www/sitiouno no está correctamente configurada para el chroot. Debe cumplir las siguientes condiciones:
Propiedad de la carpeta chroot (/var/www/sitiouno): Debe ser de root:root y no debe permitir escritura para otros usuarios.
Cambia la propiedad y los permisos:
chown root:root /var/www/sitiouno
chmod 755 /var/www/sitiouno

Subcarpeta web: Esta carpeta puede pertenecer a webuno:www-data, con permisos más abiertos:
chown webuno:www-data /var/www/sitiouno/web
chmod 755 /var/www/sitiouno/web

Revisar la configuración en /etc/ssh/sshd_config: Ahí debes asegurarte de que las siguientes directivas estén configuradas correctamente:
Match User webuno
    ChrootDirectory /var/www/sitiouno
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no

Después de aplicar estos ajustes, reinicia el servicio SSH:
systemctl restart sshd

Esto debería resolver ese problema de conexión.

Hola Stina, disculpa la demora, de nuevo has resuelto mi problema, muchas gracias, que buena informatica eres.
